# How to sort a file with a bash script using sort and getopts?

Tags: bash, shell, sorting, getopts

This is my bash script that sorts a file by columns.

```
while getopts "123456" flag

do
sort -t: -k $flag names.txt

done
```

Right now it does exactly what I need, but I need to have the filename be a parameter too.

The input right now is  ./sortScrpt -2.

I need the input to look like ./sortScript -2 names.txt

Any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: I assume you only want *one* sort parameter? (Right now I could do ./sortScript -1 -2 -3 ... -6 names.txt)

Comment: Yes, only 1 sort parameter, and then the file name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your bash script to:

```
while getopts "123456" flag

do
sort -t: -k $flag "${2}"

done
```

Getting parameters you can use "${2}" for the second parameter

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on your last sentence? I not sure what adding "${2}" will do.

Comment: When you execute the script on the prompt as follows './sortScript -2 names.txt'. You can then get this entered paramters in the script as "${1}" for the first parameter, being "-2" and "${2}" for the second parameter being "names.txt"

Answer (score 1):

Something to get you started:

```
#!/bin/bash

while getopts ":2:" opt; do
  case $opt in
    2)
      echo "-2 was triggered, Parameter: $OPTARG" >&2
      ;;
    \?)
      echo "Invalid option: -$OPTARG" >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
    :)
      echo "Option -$OPTARG requires an argument." >&2
      exit 1
      ;;
  esac
done
```

output:

```
$ ./a.sh -2 names.txt
-2 was triggered, Parameter: names.txt
```

Comment: This doesn't help at all.. All this is doing is adding some error checking.

Comment: yes it does. just add your `sort` command command in the proper place above. `-2` is in the `$opt` parameter and the filename is in `$OPTARG`

Answer (score 1):

If you want multiple sort parameters then you can update your script as:

```
#first parse -f fname    
getopts "f:" f
fname=$OPTARG

while getopts "123456" flag

do
    sort -t: -k $flag $fname
done
```

You can run this script as

```
$ ./script.sh -f names.txt -2
```

or for multiple sorts

```
$ ./script.sh -f names.txt -2 -3
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** revised for "sort-arg then file" requirement + error checking:

```
#!/bin/bash

sflag=""
sfile=""

while getopts "123456" flag
do
        [ -z "$sflag" ] && sflag="$flag"
done
shift $(($OPTIND - 1))
sfile="$1"

if [[ "$sflag" ]] && [[ "$sfile" ]];
then
    sort -t: -k $sflag $sfile
else
    # error - bail out
    echo "usage: $0 -[123456] file.txt" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

**OPTIND** is set by getopts and will either point to **$#+1** (e.g. no extra parameters) or to the first parameter not matching your getopts-flags.